# WP Multisite дочерний сайт не доступен по http

Tags: wordpress

Добрый день.

Перевел работающий по https сайт в режим мультисайта, создал дочерний сайт на поддомене, проблема в том, что дочерний сайт доступен только по https, по http нет.

Вопросы: почему он не открывается по http и как сделать чтоб он был доступен по http.

И вообще возможно ли в сети сайтов использовать оба протокола http и https

В настройках сайта (в админке wp) Siteurl и Home прописаны http://***.**.**

Comment: Попробуй теперь исправить вопрос, написав его на понятном языке и собсно  задать сам вопрос.

Comment: попробовал, задал вопрос, ответ будет?

Comment: Настройки nginx разные для обычного сайта и мультисайта: codex.wordpress.org/Nginx#WordPress_Multisite_subdomains_rul‌​es

Comment: Не увидел ни одного вопросительного знака в "вопросе", но то ладно. Да, использование 2х протоколов для одного сайта не только допустимо, но и приветствуется (правда, не всеми :)). А по главному вопросу - причин может быть много. Начиная с настроек хостинга.

Comment: Да  SeVlad проблема была непонятная, перезапустил сервер  все заработало. Про два протокола можно по подробнее,  имеется ввиду для одного мультисайта? ведь если  отдельный сайт будет доступен по http и https поисковики же с ума сойдут :)